# adding html to google chart tooltip

Tags: google-visualization

I'm using google chart api.

javascript code :

```
       var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
       data.addColumn('number', 'buy'); 
       data.addColumn('number', 'sell'); 
       data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'tooltip'});
       data.addRows( ... my data here  ... 
                   [[ 10 ,12 , "I'm very long long message in tooltip" ] [ ...  and more data.
```

the tooltip on the chart shows "I'm very long long message in tooltip" in 1 line.

how can I make the tooltip be 50px width ... or have inside 
 ?

Answer (score 7):

You should set on OPTION object the following:

```
options = {
    tooltip: {isHtml: true}
};
```

Your should also modify the line:

```
data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'tooltip'});
```

in:

```
data.addColumn({'type': 'string', 'role': 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Very helpful, never knew I should set both options.